# Optimum way to deploy two WRT54G(S) routers in a home environment?

Tags: wireless-networking, dd-wrt

I have a wrt54g and a wrt54gs. Both routers are running dd-wrt. What's the optimum way to configure them so that wireless clients can roam between them as they drop in and out of each others' range?

Comment: you have a typo in your title "64" -> "54"

Comment: "environment" is also misspelled.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- Ensure one router has DHCP turned off and is configured as an access point.
- Connect the two routers via ethernet using the non-internet ports
- Give both the same SSID / Security settings but select different channels.

The optimal way is to connect both via ethernet (e.g Cat5e). If you cannot run a cable then consider using powerline adapters. Even a "mid-speed" connection over 100mbps powerline adapters will give you a connection of 30-60mbps, far more than you'll get trying to connect them wirelessly.

Your last resort would be to setup the second router as a WDS (Wireless Distribution Station) where it acts as a wireless repeater. The problems here are that a) every repeater drops the available bandwidth by 50% and b) it needs to be close enough to get a decent signal.

Answer (score 1):

From what I gather from here, https://serverfault.com/questions/33864/how-can-i-set-up-a-single-wireless-network-through-a-number-of-wifi-routers, in your case you need to

- set up the main one as a router, the other as a bridge (inheriting and passing DHCP)
- match their SSID's
- match keys and encryption types (WPA2 AES if you can)
- assign different channels (like 6 & 11)

Answer (score 0):

Dude I so have that setup, it's cool and pretty easy if you follow this; however, I unlike you, I only have one wireless router running the DD-WRT and my wireless Linksys router connected to the Verizon DSL router-Client mode wireless rocks :-).

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Client_Mode_Wireless#Step_1

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy one as an AP and the other as a Client-Bridge. That is my setup at home.